# How do I add a row dynamically using angular js in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How do I add a row dynamically using AngularJS in a table, which contains data from a get request?

I have written a code as such:

```
<table id="tableRow" class="table table-bordered tableRow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <label>Make</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Vin</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Model</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Parts</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label></label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label></label>
            </th>
        </tr>
     <thead>
   </table>
```

now using angular js how can i add a row on click of a button or a get request in the same table...?

i had written a script which did'nt work the script is as follows..

```
$scope.myGet = function() {
                $http.get("http://172.17.133.82:8080/restproj/v1/dealer")
                    .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.addRow = response.data;
                    var tall = '';
                    tall += '<tr>'+
                        '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gs"></i></button</td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid"  ng-model="addRow.make"></td>' +  
                        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vinid" ng-model="addRow.vin"></td>'+
                        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalid" ng-model="addRow.model"></td>' + 
                        '<td ng-repeat="part in addRow.parts"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="addRow.name"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="addRow.desc"></td>' + 
                        '</tr>';

                    $('#tableROW').append(tall);                 
                });
```

I get error such as :

> tabelform.html:320 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>
> angular.min1.5.9.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…Ic%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A63139%2Fjs%2Fangular.min1.5.9.js%3A21%3A332)(…)

Comment: You are trying to inject a module that doesn't exist (or isn't loaded) into your app.
Try to post your app/controller definition

Comment: You shouldn't inject html code from a controller (try to do it without jQuery)

Comment: how to do so? in angular

Comment: btw, you have forgot to close `<thead>` you have two `thead's` now in your table

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to bind your table to a backing list and use ng-repeat to build up your table dynamically:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="carCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <td>{{ car.make }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.vin }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.model }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Your corresponding Angular script would look something like:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://172.17.133.82:8080/restproj/v1/dealer")
         .then(function (response) {
           $scope.cars = response.data.records;
           });

    });

</script>
```

Or if you want to *add* cars whenever you get an ajax response you could push them to a list (or concat the existing list, or whatever fits your case)

```
$scope.cars.push(response.data.records)
```

Angular has 2-way data binding, so if it sees that the backing list changed (e.g. by adding extra cars in the list), it will update your table dynamically.

Comment: i need to add a new input filed row in the table

Comment: You can just put the input field in it: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid"  ng-model="{{car.make}}">`

Comment: if you want to hide the input field when there is no data, you can always just use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` to hide empty input fields

Answer (score 0):

I have created A JS Fiddle For This please Refer it 
[Refer This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zmLL4pzs/)
In JS

```
 var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest()

    }).success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.people= $scope.people.concat(data);
    });
```

In HTML
    `<div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
       <p> Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load more data.</p>
       <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
       </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
    </div>`